# I'm trying to edit this wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

So I have wordpress installed on my domain. The site domain name is [kushnertech.com](http://www.kushnertech.com) . I changed the background of the site using the customize option on the wordpress admin panel. That's easy enough. However there is no option to changes the actually main content area in the middle so I went poking around in the CSS. I've messed with like every selector but I can't seem to find the right tag or class that's making the center area a bright white square. I want the body to be transparent using: `background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);` . The theme I'm using is called publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.site {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 60px auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
    width: 750px;
}
```

on line no. 915 , change background color here